# Error during VGG16 Model build on kaggle. Model is not downloading?

Tags: python, keras, kaggle

I got the following error:

```
URL fetch failure on https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/keras-applications/vgg16/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5: None -- [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
```

This is my code, I have tried to run it in my local IDE it run but in kaggle I'm  getting error, for some reason vgg16 is not downloading in kaggle :

```
base_model = applications.vgg16.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(img_rows, img_cols, img_channel))

add_model = Sequential()
add_model.add(Flatten(input_shape=base_model.output_shape[1:]))
add_model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
add_model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=add_model(base_model.output))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-4, momentum=0.9),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
```